# Pipeline failed caused by npm command not found error

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

The last week my pipeline works fine, but yesterday it failed caused of npm not found error. The pipeline was not changed since the last time it works well.

[image]

I also tried default docker image and other versions of node images, but all get the same error.

I even tried "which npm"  and got "bash: npm: command not found", seems no command is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$PATH is an environment variable which the shell uses to find commands, but I accidentally defined it again in repository settings, rename $PATH solved the problem.